# Problem with detail order in function triggered by woocommerce_new_order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I would like that after a new order has been created, an email is also sent for each product in the order, each to an address saved in an acf field of the specific product.

In the mail I want to have the details of the item as seen in the table of the classic wordpress order summary mail.

I have tried with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'create_invoice_for_wc_order',  1, 2  );

function create_invoice_for_wc_order( $order_id, $order ) {
    
    $oggetto = '';
    $corpo = '';
    $emailDaChi = $order->get_billing_email();

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        
        $emailAChi = get_field('email_gestore', $product_id); //email del gestore
        
        if ($emailAChi != '' && $emailAChi != null) {
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
            $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
            $product = $item->get_product(); // see link above to get $product info
            $product_name = $item->get_name();
            $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
            $subtotal = $item->get_subtotal();
            $total = $item->get_total();
            $tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax();
            $tax_class = $item->get_tax_class();
            $tax_status = $item->get_tax_status();
            $allmeta = $item->get_meta_data();
            $somemeta = $item->get_meta( '_whatever', true );
            $item_type = $item->get_type(); // e.g. "line_item", "fee"
            $dettaglio = wc_display_item_meta($item, array(
                    'echo' => false,
            ));
            $corpo = '
            <div> 
                <h3>
                     Riepilogo NUOVA PRENOTAZIONE:
               </h3>
               <p>

                DETTAGLI ORDINE:
                <br>'
                .$product_name.'
                <br>
                QUANTITA: '.$quantity.'
                <br>
                SUBTOTALE: '.$subtotal.'
                <br>
                TOTALE: '.$total.'
                <br>
                DETTAGLI: '.$dettaglio.'
                <br>                                   
            </p>
        </div>';
                    
            $headers = array(
                'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
                'From: '.$emailDaChi,
            );
    
            $mail = wp_mail( $emailAChi, $oggetto, $corpo, $headers);
        }
        
    }
}
```

In the mail after the string "DETTAGLI: " I see nothing.

However, if I take the code, repurpose it to pass an order id and echo the body of the mail, the details are printed out correctly.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you're calling this:

```
$emailAChi = get_field('email_gestore', $product_id);
```

...but $product_id is not yet defined at that stage, so the email (wp_mail) won't trigger.

Also, please make sure $oggetto is not empty and also you don't need this:

```
$mail = wp_mail( $emailAChi, $oggetto, $corpo, $headers);
```

... this is enough:

```
wp_mail( $emailAChi, $oggetto, $corpo, $headers);
```

Comment: Hi, You are right, $emailAChi must be declared after $product_id = ... Thanks
But that doesn't solve my problem... the email arrives but without the product details

Comment: Did you also change the other 2 things (subject & wp_mail)? Code works for me on my dev site, however I tested with a product without item meta and $dettaglio was empty. What sort of "item details" are you looking for?

Comment: Yes. In addition to woocommerce I use another plugin for Rental so I need the details chosen by the user such as the time slot selected. Adding a woocommerce_order_actions which sends the email works correctly so I'm thinking that when woocommerce_new_order is triggered the order doesn't have the details saved in it yet whereas when I triggered the action in the order it does.

Comment: Ah that makes sense alright. You should change the hook then. Try with 'woocommerce_update_order' or even better with 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' (in this case you can only pass 1 parameter, $order_id)